# Can build app in debug mode but not in release mode Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am facing following error in console when running in release mode.

```
C:\Users\Bilal Saeed\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\google_maps_flutter-2.1.0\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\googlemaps\Googl
eMapsPlugin.java:19: error: cannot find symbol
import io.flutter.embedding.engine.plugins.lifecycle.FlutterLifecycleAdapter;
                                                    ^
  symbol:   class FlutterLifecycleAdapter
  location: package io.flutter.embedding.engine.plugins.lifecycle
C:\Users\Bilal Saeed\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\google_maps_flutter-2.1.0\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\googlemaps\Googl
eMapsPlugin.java:92: error: cannot find symbol
    lifecycle = FlutterLifecycleAdapter.getActivityLifecycle(binding);
                ^
  symbol:   variable FlutterLifecycleAdapter
  location: class GoogleMapsPlugin
Note: C:\Users\Bilal Saeed\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\google_maps_flutter-2.1.0\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\googlemaps
\Convert.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: C:\Users\Bilal Saeed\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\google_maps_flutter-2.1.0\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\googlemaps
\TileProviderController.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
2 errors

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':google_maps_flutter:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 3m 14s
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...                          195.8s
Gradle task assembleRelease failed with exit code 1
```

What I have tried so far.

1. Added this line to gradle.properties.

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx4608m
```

2. In Android Studio

```
File > Invalidate Caches/Restart...
```

3. - Deleted the complete **pub_cache folder**.
   - Restarted my Android Studio.
   - Ran `flutter clean`, `flutter pub get`, `flutter upgrade`.
4. Ran flutter pub cache repair command also.

But no solution worked.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me might help some one else.

**1.** Delete .gradle file present in android folder of project.

**2.** Update classpath in project level build.gradle file by hovering over it to the latest version.

**3.**  Upgraded distribution URL in gradle-wrapper.properties

**4.** Clicked File/Invalidate Caches & restart option.
And it started to release my app once again.